# How to future-proof a reference to a page that could change

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sitemap

Simple example..

Response.Redirect("/store/packages.aspx");

I'd like to reference "/store/packages.aspx" directly from the web.sitemap file, if at all possible.  This way if some day down the line I rename or move the file packages.aspx, I don't have to find every instance of where I hard-coded the URL in my code.

What is the best method for achieving this?

Comment: this is why we have string constant's for every single URL in our system. (WebsiteUrls.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be overkill for what you're doing, but check out [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC). The short version is that it generates classes from files in your project. You then reference the generated classes' members instead of hard-coding the URL, and get a compile error if the names change and your reference hasn't been updated. It's built specifically for MVC, but the templates could probably be modified to meet your needs.

As mentioned by RPM1984, a simpler solution is to maintain a set of const fields and reference those wherever you need paths.